# Enabling horizontal scroll on Table using Jquery Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, scrollbar

I'd like to enable horizontal scroll on my table using Jquery Template.

The table structure (HTML) is :

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="shadow-wrapper">
                        <div class="tag-box tag-box-v1 box-shadow shadow-effect-2 km-table-container">
                            <script id="tblScriptMember" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
                                <tr class="pointer">
                                    <td>${MemberCode}</td>
                                    <td>${MemberName}</td>
                                    <td>${MemberCardNo}</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">{{if MemberType == 'A'}}
                                            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" disabled="disabled">
                                        {{else}}
                                            <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">
                                        {{/if}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>${MemberNIK}</td>
                                    <td>${ClientCode}</td>
                                    <td>${ClientName}</td>
                                    <td>${MemberRegistDate}</td>
                                    <td>${MemberBirthDate}</td>
                                    <td>${MemberEffStartDate}</td>
                                    <td>${MemberEffEndDate}</td>
                                    <td>${MemberModifiedDate}</td>
                                    <td>${MemberModifiedBy}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </script>
                            <table id="tblMember" class="table table-striped table-hover table-nomargin table-bordered lookup-table" style="width:1000px">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th data-field-name='MemberCode' data-sort="asc" title="Sort Member Code">Member Code</th>
                                        <th data-field-name='MemberName' data-sort="asc" title="Sort Member Name">Member Name</th>
                                        <th data-field-name='MemberCardNo' data-sort="asc" title="Sort Member Card">Member Card No</th>

                                        <th data-field-name='MemberType' data-sort="asc" title="Sort Employee Status" style="width: 20px" class="text-center">Employee</th>

                                        <th data-field-name='ClientCode' data-sort="asc" title="Sort Client Code">Client Code</th>
                                        <th data-field-name='ClientName' data-sort="asc" title="Sort Client Name">Client Name</th>
                                        <th data-field-name='MemberRegistDate' data-sort="asc" title="Sort Join Date">Register Date</th>
                                        <th data-field-name='MemberBirthDate' data-sort="asc" title="Sort Member Birthdate">Birth Date</th>

                                        <th data-field-name='MemberEffStartDate' data-sort="asc" title="Sort Member Start Date">Eff Start Date</th>
                                        <th data-field-name='MemberEffEndDate' data-sort="asc" title="Sort Member End Date">Eff End Date</th>
                                        <th data-field-name='MemberModifiedDate' data-sort="asc" title="Sort Member Modified Date">Modified Date</th>
                                        <th data-field-name='MemberModifiedBy' data-sort="asc" title="Sort Member Modifier">Modified By</th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="resultDataMember">
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                </div>
```

as you can see it running [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arisfernando_js/n5sp153u/).

I have tried the [following solution](http://jsfiddle.net/5WsEt/), using two wrapper, but my main display become un-clean and not consistent, even my tables exceeded my main display.

Would you recommend me the solution? How I can do this with this table template? Changing my table template is not my solution, because I have another function triggered within this table template events.

Very big thanks to @CerlinBoss

The only left question here is, **my footer div seems not following my table overflow style**.

There is **some empty spaces on my footer div**, take a look at my firebug component focus..
As you can see on this screen shot:

[image: footer div won't fit with my tables.]

Comment: is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/kyxee761/) what you wanted? try adding `overflow-y:auto` for `shadow-wrapper`

Comment: wow, the scroll horizontal just worked perfectly. The only question left is, when the horizontal scroll works, my footer div dont follow the table size.

please see my updated question above @CerlinBoss

Comment: and dont forget to move your suggestion to the answer @CerlinBoss, so I can vote your answer as the right ones..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `overflow-y:auto` for `shadow-wrapper`

For the space issue just check if there is any `padding` or `margin` is set.

UPDATE:

A jquery solution would be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.kamoro-table-footer').css('width',$('#tblMember').width() + "px");
})
```

Comment: no padding given on my table-footer div.
Or could you set the padding from your jsfiddle?
I have updated my jsfiddle (included your answer) here.. 
http://jsfiddle.net/arisfernando_js/secqko9o/1/

Comment: the reason for this is it takes the parent width. let me see if there is any workaround

Comment: you can do one thing. on load, get the width of table and set it to `kamoro-table-footer`

Comment: I agree with your idea, but why the div is always set to 100px..
updated.
just wow! your code was perfectly works, another things that make it more cool is the code positioning, better to place this code after I run my binding to table function. thank you!